# phpbb - How do I enable 'forum subscriptions'?

Tags: forum, phpbb

I'm having some issues in setting up Subscriptions for my phpbb forum, in that, I can't find a link to subscribe to the forum :/

Through the ACP, I've set the following to enabled:

- Allow subscribing to topics
- Allow subscribing to forums

This was done through `General > Board Configuration > Board Features`. I can't find any other section that has relevant settings that would require activation...

So, as far as I know, this should be all that's needed to enable forum subscriptions. However, when I browse my forum using both my administrator account and a newly made test account, no where do I see a link to subscribe to the forum/thread.

How do I set this up? :/

Comment: I think questions relating to configuring an application belong on http://superuser.com/ or possibly http://serverfault.com/

Comment: did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You must check if your phpBB version is the same as your phpBB template version, you can check it opening the styles/your_style/theme/themes.cfg and find the line Version.